# Stuck in an infinite loop at login on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, login-screen

I tried to fix a login loop on Ubuntu 16.04 by running

```
mv .Xauthority .Xauthority.bak
```

But this still did not fix my issue, and the log in page got really slow.

It seems like my graphics card is not working properly either

How should I fix this issue?

I already checked

Ubuntu gets stuck in a login loop

Comment: I already tried it but its not working

Comment: tried all the possible answers?

Comment: Please [edit] your post to indicate which of the over 2 dozen answers to the called duplicate question you tried, and what the results were. You can simplify this process by copying and pasting the answer via the share link near the bottom of each answer, and providing the results of your attempt beneath it. Error messages are especially useful. As it is, simply stating that you checked a question without providing any results of trying the answers given gives us less than nothing to work with. Please expend the effort to help us help you!